# Fazer um Map de Map e pegar os valores

Tags: java, for, map

Tenho um `Map` e dentro dele tenho outro `Map` e preciso fazer um `for` e pegar os valores que estão nesses *maps*, de que forma pode ser feito?

A estrutura e a forma que o `Map` está criado é assim:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapValues = new HashMap<>();

mapValues.put("laranja", Map.of("lucas", "carro"));
mapValues.put("maça", Map.of("marcos", "moto"));
mapValues.put("morango", Map.of("eduardo", "carro"));
```

O valor `laranja` corresponde a `lucas` e `carro`, assim por diante.

**Tentativa**

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : mapValues.entrySet()){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Map<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(String.format("key: %s | value: %s", key, value));
}
```

Fiz uma tentativa dessa forma, mas pelo que vi no momento que estava *debugando* é que só vou conseguir pegar o valor do primeiro *map*.

**Forma que o dado vai ser exibido**: o arquivo é um JSP portanto vou apresentar ele assim:

```
<div>
  <p><%ingrediente%></p>
  <p><%nome%></p>
  <p><%formaDeEntrega%></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia postar como gostaria de apresentar os dados?

Comment: @Danizavtz editei o poste e coloquei de qual forma vou exibir os valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os *maps* internos têm **exatamente** uma única chave, você pode obter o `entrySet` delas e pegar o primeiro (e único) elemento:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : mapValues.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    // pega a chave e o valor do map interno
    Entry<String, String> entrega = entry.getValue().entrySet().iterator().next();
    System.out.println(String.format("ingrediente: %s | nome: %s, forma de entrega: %s",
                                      key, entrega.getKey(), entrega.getValue()));
}
```

No caso, `entry.getValue()` retorna o *map* mais interno, que é um `Map<String, String>`. Depois eu pego o `entrySet` deste *map*, e `iterator().next()` pega o primeiro elemento deste *map* (que é um `Entry<String, String>`, cuja chave é o nome e o valor é a forma de entrega).

Como "temos certeza" que cada *map* interno só tem um elemento, não fiz nenhuma verificação nesse sentido, mas poderia ser feito algo do tipo:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : mapValues.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Map<String, String> formasDeEntrega = entry.getValue();
    if (formasDeEntrega.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Não há formas de entrega cadastradas para o produto " + key);
    } else {
        Entry<String, String> entrega = formasDeEntrega.entrySet().iterator().next();
        System.out.println(String.format("ingrediente: %s | nome: %s, forma de entrega: %s",
                                          key, entrega.getKey(), entrega.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Mas ainda estou assumindo que só pode ter no máximo uma forma de entrega.

Se puder ter mais de uma, aí basta fazer outro *loop* nos *maps* internos:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapValues = new HashMap<>();
mapValues.put("laranja", Map.of("lucas", "carro", "fulano", "ônibus"));
mapValues.put("maçã", Map.of("marcos", "moto", "ciclano", "caminhão", "zé", "a pé"));
mapValues.put("morango", Map.of("eduardo", "carro", "beltrano", "bicicleta"));
mapValues.put("uva", new HashMap<>());
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : mapValues.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Map<String, String> formasDeEntrega = entry.getValue();
    if (formasDeEntrega.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Não há formas de entrega cadastradas para o produto " + key);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Formas de entrega para " + key);
        for (Entry<String, String> entrega : formasDeEntrega.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format(" - nome: %s, forma de entrega: %s",
                                              entrega.getKey(), entrega.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```